# About lua for loop

Tags: function, for-loop, lua, closures

```lua
function string.split(input, delimiter)
    input = tostring(input)
    delimiter = tostring(delimiter)
    if (delimiter=='') then return false end
    local pos,arr = 0, {}
    -- for each divider found
    for st,sp in function() return string.find(input, delimiter, pos, true) end do
        table.insert(arr, string.sub(input, pos, st - 1))
        pos = sp + 1
    end
    table.insert(arr, string.sub(input, pos))
    return arr
end
```

why use

```lua
function() return string.find(input, delimiter, pos, true) end
```

after `in` , rather then use

```lua
for st,sp in string.find(input, delimiter, pos, true) do
    table.insert(arr, string.sub(input, pos, st - 1))
    pos = sp + 1
end
```

I just want to know why do this

Answer (score 3):

`for .. in` is the *generic for* statement which works with *iterators*. `string.find()` returns for only once and the return value is not an iterator so cannot be used with `for .. in`.

The Lua [doc](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5) says this:

> The *generic for* statement works over **functions**, called **iterators**. On each iteration, the iterator function is called to produce a new value, **stopping when this new value is `nil`**.

Logically speaking, the `for` loop is the same as this:

```lua
while true do
    st, sp = string.find(input, delimiter, pos, true)
    if not st then
        break
    end
    table.insert(arr, string.sub(input, pos, st - 1))
    pos = sp + 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The line you are asking about is a lambda function defining an iterator for this [lua generic for loop](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html). The generic for loop requires this argument to produce a function closure that can be called repeatedly (each time through the loop).

For more examples [see this chapter](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html)